# Is Lorenzo dangerous after he kills his family?

Tags: fallout-4

I let Lorenzo live and he killed his family when he got back to his house. Will he remain at the house, doing nothing, or is there any chance he will attack the Commonwealth or one of my settlements?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Lorenzo Cabot's wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lorenzo_Cabot), he may show up outside of a Red Rocket occasionally, but as long as he is not hostile towards you, he should be harmless.

> After finishing The Secret of Cabot House by siding with Lorenzo you can run into him at a Red Rocket just northwest of the Collegiate administration building. He examines some dead ghoul settlers and tells the player character that he killed them to study their condition.

Comment: That is correct. The Red Rocket mentioned is not the one you can have as a settlement, so this is most likely just a random occurrence that can start happening once you have finished this quest as long as you sided with Lorenzo instead of Jack.

Comment: (Although it sounds kind of terrible to equate someone to a cockroach)

Comment: I mainly meant I hoped it wouldn't be someone like Piper lying there, but yeah, I take it back, peeps are better than rad roaches